# Open explorer on a network path

Tags: python, windows, nfs

Let's say I have a network path like this below:

```
\\srv\teams\dir 1
```

How can I open it using subprocess? I am trying:

```
subprocess.Popen("explorer '\\srv\teams\dir 1'")
```

but it always leads me to my 'My Documents'. It works fine from cmd. I am using win7.

I also tried:

```
os.system("explorer '\\srv\teams\dir 1'")
```

Comment: Can you open to a path without a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see Mike Scotty for solution regarding os.system. If you use `subprocess`, please use a list of string for your command instead of a single string:

```
subprocess.call(['explorer', '\\\\srv\\teams\\dir 1'])
```

Note that I use `subprocess.call` instead of `subprocess.Popen` since this is a simple call, no need to overkill

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code:

1) Use a raw string or escape your `\` characters

2) Use `"` instead of `'` to enclose the path

```
os.system(r'explorer "\\srv\teams\dir 1"')
```

Comment: would you be able to explain why 'r' should be used before actual command?

Comment: Because it tells Python to interpret the string as a ``raw`` string, meaning ``\`` will be a literal ``\`` and not an escape character. The alternative is to escape ``\`` as shown in Hai Vu's answer.